# Nodejs cannot find module sparkles

Tags: gulp

I already installed gulp -g, and when I use "gulp tsc" I receive this message from node. Anyone can help

```
Error: Cannot find module 'sparkles'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mateus.leal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\glogg\index
.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

it says it is missing sparkles package , you should install it by running

```
npm install sparkles
```